# I would like to retrieve the height variable of mat-toolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material

"How to import the height of a toolbar into the style.scss file to use it as a common variable.

I  tried

```
@import "@angular/material/toolbar";
$my-app-toolbar-height: mat-toolbar-height();
```